# how to use gulp "main.js" which has been transpiled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, gulp

I am a beginner of the Angularjs 1.0 and my script was not working so I used `gulp` to compile ec6 to ec5 using the code below. I was able to build it and made `main.js`. How do I connect it when I launch an application? `npm related commands` not working.

I am using MVC5 for the back end so I just launch it then I can see the project going.

How do I use `main.js` to launch application or debugging application?

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./Scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))  
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});




// Compile Sass & Inject Into Browser
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./Content/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./Content"))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

// Watch Sass & Serve
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['./Content/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'scripts','sass']);
```

Comment: use script tag to refer to that `main.js`. if its environment specific, put such checks as wqell

Comment: @ShashankVivek like in View file? or bundleConfig.cs file?

Comment: You can get to know whether its `PROD` env or `DEV` env while deploying the backend code. Pass that as flag to UI, and depending on `env` use different script tag in `index.html`

Comment: @ShashankVivek can you answer that to my question so I can accept it with some examples?

Comment: Feel free to upvote as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that in **Django** framework as below:
**index.html**

```
{% if load_minified_scripts %}
   <script src="{% static "minified_assets/js/site.min.js" %}"></script>
{% else %}
   <script src="{% static "script/app.js" %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static "script/controller.js" %}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

This `load_minified_scripts` is set from server side.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_protect
@requires_csrf_token
def index(request):
    if request.session.session_key is None:
        request.session['has_session'] = True
        request.session.modified = True
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user': request.user,
                                          'debug': settings.DEBUG,
                                          'session_key': request.session.session_key,
                                          "load_minified_scripts": settings.LOAD_MINIFIED_SCRIPTS}
                  , content_type="text/html")
```

Depending on `env`, the `settings.LOAD_MINIFIED_SCRIPTS` was getting its value. For `DEV` env , it was `false`.

Similarly you can do it for other language as well.